# Selenium: Two different browsers giving back two different xpaths

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Two different pages are returning two different xpaths. In google chrome, there is a button on the webpage that says 'search'. In Firefox, however, this same button says 'search query' and the pages are structured a bit differently. How should I resolve this if tests are run by either chrome and Firefox to receive consistent results.

Comment: can u paste the link?

Comment: Please post the HTML markups from Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: just kidding. html is the same but the text of the button is different

Comment: They should have either consistent ids or class names across browsers, right? Why can't you just use that to get the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using button's text to locate it:

```
//button[. = "search" or . = "search query"]
```

or:

```
//button[contains(., "search")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with OR Condition in Xpath.Replace * with tagName

```
//*[@value='search' or @value='search query']

//*[text()='search' or text()='search query']

//*[starts-with(@value,'search')]

//*[starts-with(text(),'search')]
```